# How to increase Frama-C's GUI font/text size?

Tags: frama-c

When running `frama-c-gui`, I'd like to increase its font size (for a tutorial, class, demo, video, etc), to ensure the text is visible in a large room. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact answer may depend on system settings, but overall, these should work:

- If your Frama-C GUI has been compiled with GTK 2 (i.e. you have the opam package `lablgtk` installed but not `lablgtk3`):

  - If you are using Frama-C <= 25 (Manganese):

    There is a `frama-c.rc` file in the `share` directory of the Frama-C installation (`frama-c -print-share-path`). You can modify the lines with `font_name` by adding the desired size after the font name, e.g.:

    `font_name = "DejaVu Sans"` -> `font_name = "DejaVu Sans 18"`

    Then re-run the GUI.
  - If you are using Frama-C >= 26 (Iron):

    - The `frama-c.rc` file is not installed, so you have to manually write it. A simple way to do so is to open file `$(frama-c -print-share-path)/frama-c.rc` in your favorite text editor and then write the following:

      ```
      style "large"
      {
         font_name = "18"
      }
      widget "*" style "large"
      ```

    Save and reload the GUI.

  If none of the above work for GTK 2, in some systems it is possible to simply add/modify file `~/.gtkrc-2.0`, with a line such as:

  ```
  gtk-font-name="Noto Sans, 18"
  ```

  This will however apply to *all* GTK 2 applications. However, this has stopped working in some recent systems.
- If you are using GTK 3 (e.g. you had the opam package `lablgtk3` installed):

  Use [GTK's high DPI settings](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/HiDPI#GDK_3_(GTK_3)), such as:

  ```
  GDK_DPI_SCALE=1.33 frama-c-gui <options>
  ```

  Adjust the scale factor as you wish.